# Automorphism group of labelled Cayley graph

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, cayley-graphs

In the proof of the following statement:

**The automorphism group of labelled Cayley graph of $G$ is $G$ itself**

given here:
[Prove that the group of automorphisms of a labelled Cayley graph of a group G is the group G itself (Just stumped on one direction)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299034/prove-that-the-group-of-automorphisms-of-a-labelled-cayley-graph-of-a-group-g-is)

Part of the proof says:
"
This subgroup acts regularly (i.e. transitively and with trivial stabilizers) on $\Gamma$, so to prove that it is equal to $Aut(G)$, it is sufficient to prove that the stabilizer in $Aut(G)$ of a vertex in $\Gamma$ is trivial.
"

My question is why is this condition sufficient? 
That is why if the group acts regularly on $\Gamma$ and it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(\Gamma)$, then it is isomorphic to $Aut(\Gamma)$?

(And also I assume $Aut(G)$ in the proof should change to $Aut(\Gamma)$?)

Comment: Are you familiar with the orbit-stabilizer theorem?

Comment: Yes, how do you apply it here, assuming we have a single orbit?

Comment: If the stabilizer is trivial  then the order of the group equals the size of the orbit.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clicking. So a different way of saying this is: If the group $G$ acts regularly on a set, then since the stablizer of "a" member of the set $\Gamma$ is trivial, the size of the group is equal to the size of the set, and if the group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(\Gamma)$ then it follows that $G \cong Aut(\Gamma)$. Is this entirely correct?

Comment: Seems ok, but I don't know the details about $\Gamma$.